# Angular 5 routing issue in a feature module (force router to reload route when path is same but param changes)

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have a lazy loaded module ( documentation) and the routing file as below,

***documentation-routing.module.ts***

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: DocumentationComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                pathMatch: 'full',
                redirectTo: 'getting-started'
            },
            {
                path: 'getting-started',
                component: GettingStartedComponent
            },
            {
                path: 'products/:productname/:productVersion',
                component: ProductDocumentComponent
            }
    ]
    }
];
```

I am calling a route from an another module like this,

```
this.router.navigate([`documentation/products/${this.productRouteName}/${productVersion.version}`]);
```

and it works fine and URL becomes,

> http://localhost/documentation/products/myProductName/2.1.0

Now the problem I am facing, If I want to navigate to the same route ( by changing the version number) from within the component of documentation module , for example,

***documentation.component.ts***

```
 ProductDocumentationForAnotherVersion(e:any, version:string){
          this.router.navigate([`../products/${routeName}/${version}`]);
    }
```

the URL becomes

> http://localhost/products/myProductName/3.1.0

which is invalid.  as all URL should be based on

***http://localhost/documentation/***. , when I am calling ( for any child route) from within the documentation module

It looks something I am not doing right here.
any suggestions?

Following is the stackBlitz,
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-u7olmx

**--------UPDATE----------**

I ended-up calling like

***documentation.component.ts***

```
 ProductDocumentationForAnotherVersion(e:any, version:string){
          this.router.navigate([`documentation/products/${routeName}/${version}`]);
    }
```

and used the following way to reload the page when the route is same but the parameter value changes,

```
route.params.subscribe(param => {
            this.selectedVersion = param['clickedVersion'];
            if (this.selectedVersion) {
                this.getDocumentation(this.selectedVersion); 
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are just changing version , You can use **Relative path** :

```
this.router.navigate([`../${version}`], {relativeTo: this.activatedRoute});
```

OR **Absolute Path** :

```
this.router.navigate([`documentation/products/${routeName}/${version}`]);
```

> I would prefer the relative path for the same component route, and
>   only use absolute when it is completely diff path.

---

```
onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload' | 'ignore'
```

> How to handle a navigation request to the current URL. One of:
>
> 'ignore' : The router ignores the request. 'reload' : The router
>   reloads the URL. Use to implement a "refresh" feature.

```
RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
    onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload'
})
```

Comment: have you injected activatedRoute?

Comment: as the base path , it is taking is "localhost". I am not sure how I can maintain the base path of "localhost/documenttion" OR "localhost/documenttion/myRouteName/"

Comment: I am calling like this and I think, it is as per you suggested,  this.router.navigate([`../${version.version}`],{relativeTo:this.route});

Comment: but it is not working and URL becomes localhost/1.7.6

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197981/discussion-between-akash-and-vivek-doshi).

Comment: @Akash, found the default angular way to reload on the same component,you can also try that out

Comment: you nailed it @Vivek.  The real issue was of reloading the same route. I found a way and fixed it. all works now. Thank you for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `documentation`:

```
this.router.navigate([`documentation/products/${routeName}/${version}`]);
```

Comment: when I do this, it works but in the "product" component, I am subscribing to the param ( in this case version-number) and only that param subscription block calls when I change the version and  remaining code does not get called. So basically, the URL changes correctly but page do not get loaded/refreshed.